# FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION not working on Windows 8 32bit

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, windows-8, regedit

I have created a .NET 2.0 Winforms apps that uses the browser control to load a website which uses HTML5 features and such; on my development machine which is a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 computer after creating the necessary registry keys the page loads and works 100%, my problem is when I run it on a Windows 8 32-bit machine, even after adding the registry key it will still bomb with javascript errors which happens on the dev machine if the registry key is not created, does this trick works on Windows 8 too?

64 bit setting (used on dev machine = OK)

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "VideoChat.exe"=dword:0000270f

32 bit setting (used on Windows 8 = ERROR)

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "VideoChat.exe"=dword:0000270f

Comment: A new finding, actually the browser does run in IE10 mode, I checked that by redirecting to whatbrowser.org, the problem is that the website that I run uses a browser plugin which install for IE, Chrome and Firefox, the plugin is already installed on the standalone IE but on the in-app webbrowser it still asks about the plugin, like if it was sandboxed from the standalone IE browser, I re-installed the plugin over and over and now the page loaded but it has malfunctions whereas on the standalone IE it does not, I expected it to behave the same manner, are there any compatibility tricks known?